# Is it possible to configure the popup window to display only visible elements

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I currently have a map that contains a `MapImageLayer`with several sublayers, which I can toggle visibiliy with a `LayerList`. The problem is that, when clicking on the map, the popup opens even for invisible elements. 
[image]

Is there a way to tell the popup engine to show results for visible elements only?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me when testing with a webmap. Could you share a URL to a test case? Or more details, like are you using a webmap or PopupTemplate or ...